# Initializing/Uninitialized a jQuery plugin on page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm working with two jQuery plugins fullpage and ferromenu.

fullpage makes it so that the window scrolls by entire pages and ferromenu is a neat circular menu that expands and collapses.

The problem is that since fullpage makes my entire website one page, ferromenu is shown on every single page so I don't want to just initialize it with $(document).ready

This is what I have tried but the problem I have now is that it doesn't disappear when the page changes away from the url

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){

var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");

if (pageURL === "https://www.example.com/index.php#thirdPage") {
    $("#custom-nav").ferroMenu({
            position    : "center-center"
    });
};

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the callbacks provided by fullPage.js such as `onLeave` and `afterLoad`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#custom-nav").ferroMenu({
        position: "center-center"
    });

    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

        onLeave: function (index, nextIndex, direction) {
            //going to section 3 ?
            if (nextIndex == 3) {
                $('.ferromenu-controller').show();
            } else {
                $('.ferromenu-controller').hide();
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Or even by using the css3 class added to the body by fullpage.js as detailed in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it but I found the class for the html object it creates and just changed the display property in the else part of my if statement.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){

var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");

if (pageURL === "https://www.example.com/index.php#thirdPage") {
    $("#custom-nav").ferroMenu({
            position    : "center-center"
    });
} else {
    $('.ferromenu-controller').css('display', 'none');
};

});
```